# Microstrategy - Bar Chart in a Document does not show all the series

Tags: bar-chart, document, microstrategy

I have a bar chart in a document.

Each bar is a value of an attribute, but sadly the chart shows at most 5 columns.

I cannot find an option, in the web or the desktop, for showing 1 bar for every value in the attribute.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the report so that it produces a graph. 
Go to Graph > Graph options > Options > General.
In the second section, Scrolling, increase the maximum number of series.

Comment: Nor in the report nor in the document i can find the graph menu that you are talking about. can you post a screenshoot?

Comment: I found it but for reaching it you have to click on the chart in the document and then right click options